# How calculating green canopy cover differs from the sensor utilized

Tags: qgis, pixel, rgb, dji

I am an expert on my field.

I work with remote sensing. Mostly UAVs. I collect datasets and extract features from it. One of the features is 'green canopy cover' (https://acsess.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2134/agronj15.0150).

The formula is here:

[image: pixel based clasification]

This is pixel based clasification. For the last 3 years, I have used DJI P4 RTK for collecting the datasets (20 MP camera). This year, I started collected with the Astro Freefly and the Sony A7RIV sensor (61 MP camera). I have noticed the images from the Sony  sensor are a bit darker in comparison with the ones from DJI.
Canopy cover is calculated from the generated orthomosaic. I always follow the same procedure on Agisoft Metashape to generate it.

Both are mosaics, from DJI and from Astro, are 8-bit integer.

See here how the same green pixels are left undetected. This happens on the mosaics from Astro and not from DJI.

[image: mosaic]

[image: green canopy cover]

How calculating canopy cover differs from the sensor utilized?

Comment: I can't find proper stats on the Sony cam but this could be a difference in band wavelength. Basically one sensor collects a different wavelength area per color band than the other.